# What's the recurrence relation of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence, big-o

Is the recurrence relation below T(n) = T(n-1) + 2 + T(n+1) ?

I'm just counting the mid variable assignment and the last line, since all the if statements are excluding the other ones ... is this approach correct?

```
/* 
 * V is sorted 
 * V.size() = N
 * The function is initially called as searchNumOccurrence(V, k, 0, N-1)
 */
int searchNumOccurrence(vector<int> &V, int k, int start, int end) {
    if (start > end) return 0;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (V[mid] < k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
    if (V[mid] > k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1);
    return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1) + 1 + searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
}
```

Comment: Is this a binary search?

Comment: That looks like [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Though to calculate the number of elements with a certain value, I think one could just scan the surrounding ones when one matching element is found.

Comment: Complexity is not what you mentioned. It is T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @GAURANG VYAS in the comments. The recurrence relation is T(n)=2*T(n/2) + O(1) and is in Theta(n). [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) would be in O(log n) and its recurrence relation T(n)=T(n/2) + O(1)

Since your method `searchNumOccurrence()` looks up all occurrences of a given k it may look at all elements in V. Canonical example if all elements in V are equal to k.